# Why SO2 doesn't have dative bonds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, lewis-structure

Why doesn't the SO2 Lewis structure have, instead of two double bonds, one double bond and one dative bond? This way, the octet rule is also satisfied for sulfur.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfur_dioxide#Structure_and_bonding

Comment: **It does$ $.**